# Configuring `ray` for multiple users

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-computing, ray

Is there a way to set up a `ray` cluster so that multiple users can access it and submit jobs? I haven't been able to find anything about this in their [documentation](https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multi-user `ray` clusters are currently unsupported.

Progress can being tracked [here](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/6800).